# How to step into an interface method (Equals)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, interface, iequatable

I've implemented the iEquatable interface:

```
LineItem : IEquatable<LineItem>
```

But now I want to debug my `Equals(...)` method by stepping through the code. But even in debug mode, stepping in doesn't go into it (i.e. F11), and putting a breakpoint inside the method doesn't get me into it either. How can I debug it??

Not that it should be relevant but here is my `Equals` method:

```
public bool Equals(LineItem other)
            {
                List<bool> individuals = new List<bool>();

                individuals.Add(DateTime.Equals(Expiry, other.Expiry));
                individuals.Add(Code == other.Code);
                individuals.Add(Type == other.Type);
                individuals.Add(Class == other.Class);

                Func<object, object, bool> Compare = delegate(object A, object B)
                {
                    if (A == DBNull.Value || B == DBNull.Value)
                        return A == B;
                    else
                        return (double)A == (double)B;
                };

                individuals.Add(Compare(Strike, other.Strike));
                individuals.Add(Compare(Future, other.Future));
                individuals.Add(Compare(Premium, other.Premium));
                individuals.Add(Compare(Volatility, other.Volatility));
                individuals.Add(Compare(Volume, other.Volume));
                individuals.Add(Compare(OpenInterest, other.OpenInterest));
                individuals.Add(Compare(Delta, other.Delta));

                return !individuals.Contains(false);
            }
```

**EDIT:**
I'm calling the method from elsewhere in my code like this now:

```
if(!fo.Future.Equals(li))...
```

but that still doesn't let me debug it.

Comment: Have u checked if the debug symbols are properly pointed?

Comment: Usually a VS dialogue box shows up saying that it will step over your code. Are you getting/have got this? (you could have hit "no" which will hide the box from all future occurrences).

Comment: Are you sure your method is being called?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're stepping into `object.Equals(object)`

Comment: @EricLippert Pretty certain, here is the line that calls it `if (!LineItem.Equals(fo.Future, li))`

Comment: Please provide a *full, self-contained* example that demonstrates the issue (i.e. including the call to `Equals`, stripped down to the bare necessities to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad I don't know what that means.

Comment: @gunr2171 No I don't get any dialogue

Comment: If that is your call, then you are calling `static object.Equals(object, object)`, which is not your method. Try `fo.Future.Equals(li)`.

Comment: If the code you're calling is not in the same assembly and you're referencing the dll ... When in debug mode Goto Debug->Windows->Modules and check for the path of the dlls.

Comment: @Dan: I am pretty certain that your certainty is misplaced. You can't call an instance method as though it was a static method.

Comment: The syntax you want is probably `fo.Future.Equals(li)`.  I will also take this opportunity to note that it is a good practice to make `Equals(object)` and `==` all do the same thing if you are going to make `Equals(SomeClass)` implement value equality. It is extremely confusing to have `x.Equals(y)` and `x == y` mean completely different things.

Comment: And while we are criticizing your code: it seems very inefficient. Why do you do *all* those comparisons and *then* check to see if any is false? If the first one is false then you don't need to do any of the rest.

Comment: And also: start your `Equals` method with `if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;` That way you skip doing all that work if you know for certain that it will be true.

Comment: I agree with everyone that `fo.Future.Equals(li)` is obviously correct.But it still isn't letting me debug :/ and also I get build erros if I add `override` before my `Equals` method

Comment: Don't override *your* equals method. Override *the built-in Equals method* to *use* your method.

Comment: You need to ask a more general question here, namely, "how do I correctly implement a custom equality method?" There is a correct pattern to follow for doing this and odds are good that you're not doing it right.

Comment: Based on your experience so far today, what do you think is more likely: the debugger is broken, or you are still not calling your method correctly?

Comment: @EricLippert obviously I know the debugger isn't broken! I assumed implementing the interface meant that it would use my Equals method... I think my issue now if that sometimes the instance is null so it errors trying to call Equals rather then inside Equals... I still don't understand about the overriding though

Comment: *the debugger is broken* .. kinda humorous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LineItem.Equals(a, b)` is a static method call to `Object.Equals(object, object)`; it isn't your method.

This implementation will call `a.Equals(object)` if you've overridden it, but you did not override it.

Comment: I don't understand your second point about the overriding? I agree with the first, but changing it as in my edit hasn't helped :(

Comment: @Dan: `li` is probably of compile-time type `Object`, so you're calling `object.Equals(object)` and not your function.  You should probably override `Equals(object)` to call your function.

Comment: But which `Equals(object)`? inside my `LineItem` class? I get an error if I try that

Answer (score 15):

You need to take a big step back and learn how to implement equality methods correctly in the first place. C# was designed to be a "pit of success" language; that is, you should naturally "fall into" doing things the right way. Unfortunately, equality is not a "pit of success" in C#; the language designers failed to make it easy to do it right the first time.

Here's the pattern that I use when I override equality.

First, start by writing a *private static method* that does *everything right*.  Everything else will use this method. Start your method by dealing with (1) the reference equality early out, and (2) null checks.

```
private static MyEquality(Foo x, Foo y)
{
  if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
  // We now know that they are not BOTH null.  If one is null
  // and the other isn't then they are not equal.
  if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
  if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
  // Now we know that they are both non-null and not reference equal.
  ... check for value equality here ...
}
```

OK, now that we have that, we can use that to implement everything else.

```
public override bool Equals(object y)
{
  return MyEquality(this, y as Foo);
}
public override int GetHashcode()
{
  // Implement GetHashcode to follow the Prime Directive Of GetHashcode:
  // Thou shalt implement GetHashcode such that if x.Equals(y) is true then 
  // x.GetHashcode() == y.GetHashcode() is always also true.
}
public bool Equals(Foo y)
{
  return MyEquality(this, y);
}
```

That is what is *necessary* to correctly implement `IEquatable<T>.Equals`. You should also *consider* overriding the `==` operator to be consistent:

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo x, Foo y)
{
    return MyEquality(x, y);
}
public static bool operator !=(Foo x, Foo y)
{
    return !MyEquality(x, y);
}
```

Now no matter whether you call `object.Equals(foo, bar)`, `foo.Equals(bar)`, or `foo == bar`, you have consistent behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, although I'm still not sure where iEquatable fits in then? Anyway, the issue was that I was calling the object method instead of the instance method. Now I can debug!

Comment: @Dan: `IEquatable<Foo>` requires that you implement `public bool Equals(Foo foo)`. I did so.

Comment: @Dan: A more precise characterization is: the issue was that *the object method* and *your method* did *different things*. They should always do *the same thing*, which they do if you follow the correct pattern, as I described.

Comment: Oh right, so we're assuming the class all that live in has a `:iEquatable` afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah but in this case I'm happy for the object method and the `==` method to compare instances rather than values. But I'll keep this in mind for the future

Comment: @Dan: Doing so is an extremely poor programming practice. The .NET Framework Design Guidelines indicate that it is *reasonable* to make `==` mean reference equality and `Equals` mean value equality but many people myself included find classes which do so to be confusing. It is definitely a poor practice to make `Equals(Foo)` have value semantics and `Equals(object)` (or, equivalently, `Equals(object, object)`) to have reference semantics. That is a recipe for bugs.

Comment: Eric, thank you for clarying. People thought I am nuts in overriding the equality operator for reference types. Look at this FxCop rule, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182145(v=vs.80).aspx , which says not to overload Equals operator for reference type. I think this is what Java did with their string types. To compare strings, you had to use Equals method as the equals operator would only do reference comparison.

Comment: @SolutionYogi: I don't think you're nuts. :-)  For me, the question is whether reference types ought to have value equality at all. My preferences are from best to worst: (1) reference types use reference equality, (2) reference types use value equality consistently for all forms of equality, (3) reference types use value equality for `Equals` and reference equality for `==`, and (4) everything else.

Comment: @Dan `IEquatable<T>.Equals` should be identical to `object.Equals`. Its main point is that calling it avoids boxing for value-types. | One point Eric didn't mention concerning good vs. bad equals is that custom equality is usually a bad idea on mutable types. A good example of custom equality is `System.String` which is immutable and all of the above methods (`object.Equals`, `IEquatable<T>.Equals`, `==`, `!=` and `GetHashCode`) are consistent.